# PostSharp Cache Sample NOT working outside of the sample solution

Tags: .net, caching, postsharp

PostSharp's Cache sample project works, but when I copy all classes and try to replicate it on my own solution, Cache does NOT happen. But build does not fail, so there must be something going on. Any tips?

Comment: +1. Thanks for pointing me in the direction of the sample code for caching.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Apparently, you have to modify the .proj file to make sure POSTSHARP is building it. Read through the step carefully at http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/documentation/enabling-postsharp

Comment: Indeed, samples have a special setup that works only when they are run from the installation directory. If you move the sample, you have to reconfigure the project file as if it were a normal project.